# How can I attach a PDF whens ending mail in Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

In Sales > Invoices when Send Email is clicked, I need a PDF to be attached to the email. I'm using Magento 2.3.3.

```
$pdf = 'path to pdf';
$this->configureEmailTemplate();

$this->transportBuilder->addTo(
 $this->identityContainer->getCustomerEmail(),
 $this->identityContainer->getCustomerName()
);

$copyTo = $this->identityContainer->getEmailCopyTo();

if (!empty($copyTo) && $this->identityContainer->getCopyMethod() == 'bcc') {
   foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
       $this->transportBuilder->addBcc($email);
   }
}

//$transport = $this->addAttachment($pdf, $pdfFileName);
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->addAttachment($pdf, 'test');
$transport = $this->transportBuilder->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();`
```

I tried to write addAttachemtment function to the customized transportBuilder page. But it didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?